# Shopware 6 - Multiple Images and Variant Images how to get?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

1. Some Products has multiple "main" images. But I see only one if I check the product with the API endpoint `store-api/product/productid`, is there a different endpoint for checking images ?
2. I need the image from "Citrus-Quark", but there is no `mediaId` or media, but it has a different image in the frontend. How can I get it then?

The Shopware 6 store-api docu is a little slim.

```
"options": [
                {
                    "groupId": "16f64239b6b14be9b0c173f10e415105",
                    "name": "Citrus-Quark",
                    "position": 0,
                    "colorHexCode": null,
                    "mediaId": null,
                    "group": null,
                    "media": null,
                    "_uniqueIdentifier": "6a8f8be85eed4097bba6866cf220cab5",
                    "versionId": null,
                    "translated": {
                        "name": "Citrus-Quark",
                        "position": 0,
                        "customFields": {
                            "emz_migration_legacyId": 1985
                        }
                    },
                    "createdAt": "2022-05-21T21:00:00.822+00:00",
                    "updatedAt": null,
                    "extensions": {
                        "foreignKeys": {
                            "apiAlias": "array_struct"
                        }
                    },
```

Comment: Good question, I guess you would need to need the `product.media` / `product.cover` association - which seems not possible out of the box in the store API.

Comment: i got /api access now, i get the varitnas but there is no media